# How to view the taken pictures in Android Without using Database?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Hai am new in Android Application.i Generated a code to take picture by using Camera.Now i want to view the Taken Pictures without using Database.i dont know how to do this.AnyBody please help me.
Thanks in advance
Here my Code

```
private void createCamera() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   preview = new Preview(this);
   ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);

   buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
   buttonClick.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
         preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
      }
   });

  Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
}

ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
   public void onShutter() {
      Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
   }
};

/** Handles data for raw picture */
PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
   public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
      Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
   }
};

/** Handles data for jpeg picture */
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
   public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
      FileOutputStream outStream = null;

      try {
         outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis())); 
         outStream.write(data);
         outStream.close();
         Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {}

      Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
   }
};

private void createpictures() {
   img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

   ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setType("image/*");
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
         startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
      }
   });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
         Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
         selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
         System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
         img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
      }
   }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
   String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
   Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
   int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: The Taken pictures are Saved in Gallery(automatically)

Answer (score 1):

Simple as this:

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("file://"+yourFileName));
startActivity(in);
```

Default app for viewing pictures will start, or if there's no default, user get selection dialog which app to use.

Answer (score 0):

you really dont need to use database to view taken picture.

1. To get new image - open an intent for Camera. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574313/using-intent-to-use-camera-in-android)
2. To see all other captured images, open Gallery. see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

heres a good overview of opening data via intents on your phone. All this documentation is in here as well http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html but not as clear to follow.

http://indyvision.net/2010/03/android-using-intents-open-files/

```
 File imageFile2View = new File("/sdcard/nice_photo.jpeg");
 Intent i = new Intent();
 i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(imageFile2View), "image/jpeg");
 startActivity(i);
```

Now if what your looking for is to display the picture you took in your own activity you can use.

```
String file = String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
//SAVE IMAGE TO file
img.setImageURI(URI.parse(file));
```

or

```
String file = String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
//SAVE IMAGE TO file
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);
img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```